# Will MD5( libcrypto ) work on string which contain null in between?

Tags: c, encryption, md5

I have two strings as below
Str1:  1234\099
Str2:  123499

If I calculate MD5 on these string using unsigned char *MD5(const unsigned char *d,                  unsigned long n, unsigned char *md);

Will the function MD5 calculate the hash for first 4 bytes of Str1 or would it take the complete string "1234\099".

Will the MD5 of Str1 and Str2 be same or different????

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Michael is right. I executed the below program and it seems that MD5 calculation takes place on second argument irrespective of what is in the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>

int main() { <br>
    char *p = NULL;<br>
    char *c = NULL;<br>
    char *q = NULL;<br>

    p = malloc(10*(sizeof(char)));
    strncpy(p, "ABCDEDFGO", 9);
    c = malloc(200*(sizeof(char)));
    memset(c,0, 200);

    p[3] = '\0';

    q = MD5(p, 9, c);
    printf("\n For 9 bytes hash %x", *c);
    q = MD5(p, 4, c);
    printf("\n For 4 bytes hash %x", *c);
    q = MD5(p, 3, c);
    printf("\n For 3 bytes hash %x", *c);

    free(c);
    return (0);
}
```

For 9 bytes hash ffffffc9 
 For 4 bytes hash ffffffe5 
 For 3 bytes hash ffffff90

Answer (score 3):

That all depends on what value you pass for the `n` parameter.

If you use `strlen()` to calculate `n`, then the `MD5()` function will process data up to, but not including, the null (because you told it to, in effect).

If you pass in the correct length for `n` (I assume that's `7` for `Str1`), then `MD5()` will include all the data in the hash, including null bytes and data past the null.

The hash for `Str1` and `Str2` will be different (assuming you pass in something larger than 3 for `n`).

Answer (score 0):

`const unsigned char *d` it's firs element of array, not C-style string.

So specify proper length (7 elements) of `(const unsigned char *)"1234\099"` you will obtain its MD5 into `md`.